# XADES-EPES Dudas sobre los valores en los DigestValue y SignatureValue

Tags: xml, firma-digital

Estoy integrando firma digital XADES-EPES en PHP sobre el estándar UBL, he leído bastante sobre le tema y en varios repositorios hacen de distintas formas el firmado, vaya, lo que va dentro de los **DiguestValue** y **SignatureValue** dejándome finalmente con la duda de: **que información realmente va en esos elementos?**.

Para verificar mis avances y llegar al firmado correcto me estoy respaldando en este validador **https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml** y he abierto un repositorio donde comparto mi código en PHP hasta donde lo llevo de avanzado: **https://gitlab.com/siegroupmx/xmlsinger**

Voy al asunto....

**>> Como se generan los DigestValue para las Referencias dentro de SignedInfo ??**

Mi procedimiento para esto es simplemente tomar el Nodo (por ejemplo KeyInfo) canonizado a C14N y después lo paso por un Algoritmo (sha1, sha256, etc...), después lo convierto a Base64 y el resultado lo coloco sobre **DigestValue**, **mi proceso es correcto** ???

Ejemplo simple y rápido:

> Sobra mencionar que en el ejemplo de abajo estoy omitiendo el proceso
>   donde creo la etiqueta Singature y sus elementos internos.

```
<?php
const XMLDSIGNS= 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#';

$xmlSigned= 'mixml.xml';
$xml= new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace= FALSE;
$xml->formatOutput= true;
$xml->load($xmlSigned);

$xp= new DOMXPath($xml);
$xp->registerNamespace('secdsig', self::XMLDSIGNS);
$keyinfo= $xp->query('.//secdsig:Signature/secdsig:KeyInfo');

$hash= hash("sha256", $keyinfo->item(0)->C14N(), true);
$base64= base64_encode($hash);
echo $base64; # imprime LcOJdpKtT7sgjbblkmGyYrSUslXMlw0TyCc8SOUBJQM=
?>
```

Y en el XML:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-a837805e-9235-a8bb-7ab4-688282608259-keyinfo">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>LcOJdpKtT7sgjbblkmGyYrSUslXMlw0TyCc8SOUBJQM=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
....
....
<ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-a837805e-9235-a8bb-7ab4-688282608259-keyinfo">
    ... todas las etiquetas internas....
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

**>> Como se genera el SignatureValue ???**

En mi procedimiento tomo el nodo de **SignedInfo** canonizado a C14N, los firmo con **openssl_sign()** y el resultado lo convierto a Base64 y coloco dentro de SignatureValue. **Es correcto esto que hago** ???

Ejemplo rápido:

```
<?php
const XMLDSIGNS= 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#';

$xmlOut= 'mixml.xml';
$xml= new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace= FALSE;
$xml->formatOutput= true;
$xml->load($xmlOut);

$xp= new DOMXPath($xml);
$xp->registerNamespace('secdsig', self::XMLDSIGNS);

$si= $xp->query('.//secdsig:Signature/secdsig:SignedInfo'); # signedinfo
openssl_sign($si->item(0)->C14N(), $signature, $this->privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
$dato= base64_encode($signature); # esto va en SignatureValue

$sv= $xp->query('.//secdsig:Signature/secdsig:SignatureValue'); # signaturevalue
$sv->item(0)->nodeValue= $dato;
?>
```

Y el **SignatureValue** dentro del XML esta:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-bfcdf0f0-2655-b952-9c85-77493d9f241f">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-bfcdf0f0-2655-b952-9c85-77493d9f241f-ref0" URI="">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>KWOvQ3tWaygQXkkvfI6s9UO0azjQgc0YGp9JANDXYis=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
        <ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-a837805e-9235-a8bb-7ab4-688282608259-keyinfo">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>LcOJdpKtT7sgjbblkmGyYrSUslXMlw0TyCc8SOUBJQM=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-bfcdf0f0-2655-b952-9c85-77493d9f241f-sigvalue">
        ZGcaOhKK3Uzp64T11LHFKAy1eOkKeMpvKNNAeBFapJxbyCr8iQDkGQ2B+VQFYLWZnDneK6Cuc6uDtUw14q4mlYoarlIRVvLlsiQK0OmFrdWEM4sd62WPP2N0GpUOOh/I/BjggsqNV1OOWG2xutZNbdh4maJzxEbcLuU8SrdPuU6q38bTAw/QJyQ5F4eiRr++28sR9G3yV0nTzkZXR5QNPScdrbwrMtH/vkBx0FfV8ErzubwKyPdvQSbugmLMk8hd7Rnn5SRg8JaxQhCC5TDPC3KOmj5Nh1zHmzATZaRAbP0XNoYsDLnQtmteo5/RL2NHGvHYbP0teUF43nHXu/KAVg==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
```

**>> CONCLUSIÓN**

El validador me dice que la Firma esta mal, y que también esta mal el firmado de las referencias :(

Enlace a un ejemplo **https://gitlab.com/siegroupmx/xmlsinger/blob/master/examples/ejemplo_out.xml**

Certificado: https://gitlab.com/siegroupmx/xmlsinger/blob/master/tmp/certificado.pem

Firma: https://gitlab.com/siegroupmx/xmlsinger/blob/master/tmp/firma.pem

Clave: persona_juridica_pruebas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de **4 días** que parecieron "eternos" finalmente solucione mi problema.

El proceso en como realizaba los **DigestValue** de las Referencias y el **SignatureValue** son totalmente correctos, el problema radicaba en la Canonización.

Al momento de carga el XML firmado, extraer un nodo y generar la referencia estaba generando una apertura incorrecta lo cual seteaba **por defecto** la canonización en "preservar espacios" lo cual resultaba un hash distinto al esperado, ya que al momento de declarar el **Transform** para cada Reference, se indicaba un C14N regular, mas no un C14N-WithComments.

Antes:

```
    $xml= new DOMDocument();
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace= FALSE;
    $xml->formatOutput= true;
    $xml->load($xmlsrc);
    $xmldata= $xml->C14N();
```

Correcto:

```
    $xml= new DOMDocument();
    $xml->formatOutput= true;
    $xml->load($xmlsrc);
    $xmldata= $xml->C14N();
```

Este simple detalle me permitió generar el Firmado Xades-Epes sin problemas, ahora todas las tools me marcan "pass/valid" el firmado de las referencias como del SignatureValue.

Saludos !

Comment: Por favor una ayuda. me sale error Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active
cuando dejo self::XMLDSIGNS .
En que parte enlazas el certificado digital. gracias.

Comment: @user191033 estas probando el ejemplo que coloque? o estas haciendo algo personal?