# ¿Cómo canonizar con C14N con sangría y retorno de carro en PHP sin NameSpace?

Tags: php, xml, firma-digital

Estoy luchando para conseguir que el objeto datos esté intacto o que los hash coincidan, por decirlo más claro. Al parecer el C14N tomas diferente los retornos de carro y las sangrías (identition para los que les gustan los anglicismos)  cuando se crean por `$nodoDeMisAmores = $xml->createElement("blablabla");` que cuando se pasan a una variable con `$texto = $xml->sabeXML();`. Al menos es lo que dice la plataforma de la Comisión Europea donde pruebo (https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation)

Según la documentación de PHP, los retornos de carro y sangrías deberían respetar cuando creas el XML así:

```php
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->formatOutput=true;

$TicketBai=$xml->createElement("T:TicketBai");
$xml->appendChild($TicketBai);
$QualiAtributo = $xml->createAttribute("xmlns:T");
$QualiAtributo -> value = "urn:ticketbai:emision";
$TicketBai->appendChild($QualiAtributo);
$QualiAtributo = $xml->createAttribute("xmlns:ds");
$QualiAtributo -> value = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
$TicketBai->appendChild($QualiAtributo);
$QualiAtributo = $xml->createAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
$QualiAtributo -> value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
$TicketBai->appendChild($QualiAtributo);
$QualiAtributo = $xml->createAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation");
$QualiAtributo -> value = "urn:ticketbai:emision ticketBaiV12.xsd ";
$TicketBai->appendChild($QualiAtributo);

$Cabecera=$xml->createElement("Cabecera");
$TicketBai->appendChild($Cabecera);
```

Pero cuando le has terminado el XML y haces:

```php
$canonizado = $xml->C14N(false);
echo $canonizado;
```

Devuelve una línea con todas las etiquetas una tras otra (C14N debe estar en "false" cuando se opta por la canonización http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116 si no entendí mal). Esto aparentemente contraviene las especificaciones del W3C apartado 2.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/).

Según la documentación de PHP, con `$xml = formatOutput=true;` los retornos de carro y sangrías se respetan pero su función de canonización C14N no lo hace, generando un problema cuando está el XML terminado y se debe firmar digitalmente con XadES-cualquierVersión porque en el momento que se ignore un solo carácter la hemos liado por el efecto avalancha.

He visto de moneyBox utiliza en [XADES-EPES Dudas sobre los valores en los DigestValue y SignatureValue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245699/xades-epes-dudas-sobre-los-valores-en-los-digestvalue-y-signaturevalue?rq=1) la constante `const XMLDSIGNS= 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#';`, constante que no he sido capaz de hallar en la documentación de PHP por más que he mirado (https://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php)

¿Alguna alternativa?

Muchas gracias porque da la sensación que la clave para una firma digital válida es la canonización, lo demás parece mucho más fácil.

¡¡¡LO CONSEGUÍ!!! ¡¡¡LO CONSEGUÍ!!! ¡¡¡LO CONSEGUÍ!!! ¡¡¡LO CONSEGUÍ!!!

Atentos a todo lo que hay que hacer:

1. Fuera el `$xml->formatOutput=true;` Esa línea comentada. Ni false ni puñetas.
2. Cuando se ha terminado de crear el XML aplicamod el hash (yo elegí el sha512) y codificamos en base64, pero no a $texto porque queda el último paso.
3. Cortar 39 caracteres por delante y uno por detrás. Así:

`$base64 = base64_encode(hash('sha512', substr($texto, 39, -1), true));`

Tiene bemoles la cosa ¿verdad? Supongo que habrá una fórmula más corta, pero paso de seguir probando.

Por supuesto con KeyInfo no funciona y tampoco el siguiente DigestValue, probablmente por los espacios de nombre (los NameSpace o ns) aunque sigue siendo un progreso.

Aquí utilizan un método totalmente diferente, nada de generación por programación, https://gist.github.com/josemmo/f88e566b67c2579e3fbf1ec90a00ad24

Comment: de ser asi como lo indicas puede ser un bug o un problema de version de php o de la libreria ... tienes algun escenario de prueba con las versiones etc? has subido algun request de validacion del bug a php.net?

Comment: ahora haciendo una burda prueba el xml canonizado muestra esto en la cabecera:  `<?xml version="1.0"?>` mientras que el xml sin canonizar muestra eso: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` el sharset es removido ... no sera por aqui que va el problema?

Comment: si cambias esta linea:  `$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");` por esta `$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");` el xml y el xml canonizado resultan identicos ... agregar `UTF-8` a `DOMDocument` agregara esto como atributo ...

Comment: me avisas si te funciona ...

Comment: Por supuesto que te aviso y muchas gracias por el esfuerzo. Estoy buscando otro servidor. Para ver si es lo que dices de un posible fallo. Perdona por favor que soy un novato en esto de preguntar.

Comment: Lo que yo veo cuando imprimo desde otro servidor la variable $canonizado es que desaparece <?xml version="1.0"?> o cualquier otra versión de la misma etiqueta, como en principio debería ser. Pero sigue poniendo todas las etiquetas en línea

Comment: No sé si está el problema en añadirle más parámetros la DOM. Quizá sea el propio DOM el que hay que abandonar y hacerlo en SAX o alguna de esas librerias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139679/discussion-between-zosimo-and-arcanisgk507).